# Parsed number with soup trying to turn it into an int

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a number parsed from the html page on the internet with BeatifulSoup.

the method I used is

```
number = soup.find('div',class_= "html text").text
```

If I `print(number)`in the IDE console it's all good it shows me 15,035,489

I took the number and copy it to an excel workbook page using this code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\me\path\MyExcelFile.xlsm')
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = number
```

So far so good just that the number doesn't show as an integer in fact it doesn't show at all on the check bar up only in the cell inside the excel page.

I tried to convert the number from string to integer in my IDE and after that to copy it.

```
 number_int = int(number)
```

Obviously it's not working I get the error bellow:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n\n15,035,489 \n'. I guess I have to strip it now of those blank spaces or something to get rid of the \n around it. How do I do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `.get_text(strip=True)` instead of `.text`

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method with `strip=True` instead of `.text`.
For example:

```
number = soup.find('div',class_= "html text").get_text(strip=True)
```